# Excel, cut-n-paste ERROR-MESSAGE: "The picture is too large and will be truncated."

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste, microsoft-excel-2010

**ISSUE:** Possible it's not related, but I just installed IE9, and now I'm getting this an error when I try to copy-n-paste a relatively small amount of text:

### Excel Error Message:

```
"The picture is too large and will be truncated."
```

**NOTE:** I have Googled this error message, but nothing I've found yet appears to work for my system's profile.

---

### System Profile:

- **EXCEL:** Microsoft Office Home and Business 2010
- **OS:** Windows 7
- **MISC:** IE9

---

**Questions, feedback, requests -- just comment, thanks!!**

Comment: @blunders: is the picture actually being truncated? i get similar messages in excel 2011 all the time without actually losing any data.

Comment: to clear the obvious, you've tried rebooting and you've made sure all applicable OS and Excel/Office updates are installed?

Comment: @Xantec: Yes, I've checked the update status of each, though not 100% sure they're current.

Comment: @bboyreason: Good question, there is no image -- based on my research Excel is converting the text to an image for the clipboard service. One site suggested on uninstall the service, but I've been unable to figure out how to do this on the platform covered above, or confirm that for some strange reason an image got embedded by mistake. Additional questions, just ask - thanks!

Comment: So, is it Copy or Paste?

Comment: (And why the UPPER CASE, the odd formatting with **ALL THE BOLD** and such, and the rollback of @Randolph's edit, putting all that noise back into the question?)

Comment: @Arjan: #1 reason that I did the rollback of @Randolph's editing is he deleted text stating that I am open to any "Questions, feedback, requests" -- it's important info. Also, good question, the error was given on COPY. Also, appear to have found an answer, and have posted it. Meaning after to the procedure, I'm no longer getting the error, though I still to not know the source of the issue. Thanks!!

Comment: Er, you think others are not open to that...? To me, it actually could be read as "I'm *sure* my question is not complete, let's add some obvious note about Google, and then let's just post anyway..." ;-) (The answer has a bit too much formatting for my liking too, but still +1 for reporting back.)

Comment: @Arjan: "obviously" you're wrong.. :-) ..most people don't Google an issue before posting. And yes, I always post updates, even if I did something dumb... :-) ...Cheers!

Comment: just by the by, I have experienced this issue as well while running TeamViewer in the background. My guess is that TV is somehow hooking into the copy event and doing something funny in order to prep for potential sending to a remote machine. If I close TeamViewer I no longer have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This appears to have fixed the issue:**

- [MS Excel 2007 error message - The
  picture is too large and will be
  truncated__Not a 'picture' - it's
  text in MS Excel 2007 that's being
  copied](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/ms-excel-2007-error-message-the-picture-is-too/f9932485-43b7-4f73-af82-1f6f1f559438)

**That being, clear the temp folder:**

1. Click on Start > All Programs > Accessories > Run
2. Copy and paste "`%temp%`" into the ‘OPEN’ field and then press ‘ENTER’ key; Note: ensure all applications are closed before deleting the files.
3. Delete all the files and folders from the above location.

Answer (score 3):

Just found [this answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/ms-excel-2007-error-message-the-picture-is-too/f9932485-43b7-4f73-af82-1f6f1f559438), which proved to be the source of the problem for me.

It was the clipboard synchronization feature in TeamViewer that caused the error, so simply closing TeamViewer fixed is, and would turning that feature off.

> Or if you have TeamViewer (TeamViewer is a Remote Access Program), just go to "Extras > Options > Advanced > Clipboard synchronization"  and disable this option and everything will be fine and the problem will go away.
>
> Note: you need to restart TeamViewer.

Comment: +1 Realize that you had a similar issue (that is, error message), but that does not mean that the origin of issues to a single error message means that all issues originate from the same source; case in point, the system in questions was built from scratch by me, and did not have TeamViewer installed. Also, please do not read this comment as anything more than it is, which is more of an abstract bit of feedback on your answer, than a comment on the value of your answer. Thank you for sharing, and glad to hear you found a solution too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution/cause seems to involve Actual Windows Manager and the clipboard features.  I was seeing this issue (The picture is too large and will be truncated) and tried all the tricks such as deleting the cache and repairing the Office applications to no avail.  I remembered some settings in the Actual Windows Manager utility that I'd seen some time ago.  I went into the configuration for Clipboard in the AWM application and disabled clipboard templates, and clipboard history and the problem was finally resolved.  I'm going to pass the issue to AWM support to see if they can remedy the problem that appears to be related to their utility.